# What is the difference b/w resource view and header view in ieHTTPHeader w.r.t favicon.ico request?

Tags: internet-explorer, http-headers, favicon

IE requests internally for the favicon.ico which is normally seen in resource view in ieHTTPHeader. One of my customer's ieHTTPHeader shows this request in headers view and they face problem in opening pop-up window that is served through our code which generate HTML content for this window using for loop and if else condition to serve 4 parts of pop-up window. Because of the favicon.ico request pop-up window hangs as it is waiting to serve favicon.ico request.

How to get rid of favicon.ico request? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you demonstrate how the pupup window "hangs"? I don't really understand. Does IE expect to show the content only after the favicon is received, but your server can only handle one connection at a time?

Comment: @Bergi When we get request for favicon.ico,we do not send reply and wait for next request to come from IE, but IE is waiting for favicon request to be replied by the server and does not send the request.

Comment: @Pekka Could you please tell me if there is an IE setting that could result in sending the favicon.ico request while the page is being rendered?

Comment: Why not just send a reply for the favicon?

Comment: @Bergi At the time when we get the favicon.ico request( In the scenario when application crashes) we actually are in the middle of sending HTML for the pop-up window GUI. There are 3 parts of this window and through for loop we serve it. We can see the request that comes for favicon.ico and trying to serve in else part in the for loop...